# Как запустить JS скрипт в JS скрипте?

Tags: javascript

Нужно в JS коде сделать при запуске, запуск другого скрипта. Или, если так нельзя то файл .bat.
Пробовал:
node index

Comment: [child_process.execSync()](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options) или eval()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если речь про окружение ноды, то можно просто require сделать динамически и скритп выполнится.

Answer (score 0):

Просто подключите в скрипте другой скрипт:

```
require('./other.js');
```

Comment: Во прикол! реально работает